# How to conditionally attach/detach bootstrap datepicker with textbox

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

My objective is to dynamically attach/detach bootstrap datepicker with textbox. Based on drowdown value I would like to attach/detach  bootstrap datepicker with textbox. I tried below way but it is not working.....what I am missing there?

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-2'>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-lg-1">
        <select id="dddata">
          <option value="Text">Text</option>
          <option value="Date">Date</option>
        </select>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
var $htmlelement = $('<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>');

var isDate = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  SetUPUI();
  $("#dddata").change(function() {
    SetUPUI();
  });
});

function SetUPUI() {
  if ($('#dddata').val() == "Date") {
    alert('pp');
    $('#datetimepicker1').append($htmlelement);
    $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      format: "mm/dd/yyyy"
    });
  } else {
    $("#datetimepicker1").remove($htmlelement);
    $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker('remove');
  }
}
```

### browser console showing this error

> jquery-1.9.1.js:4370 Uncaught TypeError: expr.replace is not a
>   function
>       at Function.Sizzle.matchesSelector (VM235 jquery-1.9.1.js:4370)
>       at Function.filter (VM235 jquery-1.9.1.js:5757)
>       at init.remove (VM235 jquery-1.9.1.js:5986)
>       at SetUPUI ((index):87)
>       at HTMLDocument. ((index):68)
>       at fire (VM235 jquery-1.9.1.js:1037)
>       at Object.add [as done] (VM235 jquery-1.9.1.js:1083)
>       at init.ready (VM235 jquery-1.9.1.js:275)
>       at (index):66
>       at dispatch (VM235 jquery-1.9.1.js:3074) Sizzle.matchesSelector @ jquery-1.9.1.js:4370 filter @ jquery-1.9.1.js:5757 remove @
>   jquery-1.9.1.js:5986 SetUPUI @ (index):87 (anonymous) @ (index):68
>   fire @ jquery-1.9.1.js:1037 add @ jquery-1.9.1.js:1083 ready @
>   jquery-1.9.1.js:275 (anonymous) @ (index):66 dispatch @
>   jquery-1.9.1.js:3074 elemData.handle @ jquery-1.9.1.js:2750

Comment: Troubleshooting 101: Define "is not working" (those words are useless for troubleshooting).  What does it do? Does it do it wrong? Does it do nothing? Have you used your browser's console to check for errors? etc. etc. etc.  For example, does your `alert('pp');` fire?  **NOTE:** If the issue is that your datepicker code fires, but the datepicker doesn't work, it's because a datepicker should be bound to the input, not to the containing element.

Comment: no alert fire. probably error is there.

Comment: console error attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var $htmlelement=$('<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>');

var isDate=0;

function SetUPUI()
{
    if($('#dddata').val()=="Date")
    {
        alert('pp');
        $('#datetimepicker1').append($htmlelement);
        $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,  
        format: "mm/dd/yyyy"
        }); 
    }
    else
    {
        $htmlelement.detach();  // to dynamically remove the html 
           $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker('destroy'); // you was using remove that is deprecated and replace with "destroy"
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () 
{
    //SetUPUI();
    $("#dddata").change(function () {
        SetUPUI();
    });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-2'>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-lg-1">
<select id="dddata">
  <option value="Text">Text</option>
  <option value="Date">Date</option>
</select>            
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not useful.  What did you change? Why does it work? Offer some explanation, or comment your code.

Comment: @cale_b, i have added this code $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker("option", "disabled", true);

Comment: sorry for not providing explanation, i  was creating fiddle for the same.

Comment: @MonojitSarkar, please check the snippet code, its working now

Comment: @MonojitSarkar, my pleasure

Comment: this two line causing problem `$htmlelement.detach();
$('#datetimepicker1').datepicker('destroy');`  ?

Comment: this two line causing problem `$htmlelement.detach();
$('#datetimepicker1').datepicker('destroy');`  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164703/discussion-between-sudhakar-and-monojit-sarkar).

Comment: i just need highlight those area what you change in html and jquery code.

Comment: @MonojitSarkar, i have commented those two line, please go through it and let me know if you want anything else.

Answer (score 1):

There were multiple problems.  The main one was that you were using jQuery to create your `$htmlelement` *before* the document ready, and jQuery was NOT loaded, so it was throwing an error.  (Note, your Browser's Developer Console is a powerful, useful tool.  Learn to use it - it'll save you TONS of time finding problems).

Below is a commented version of your code, modified to work properly.  (Note - made as a snippet, so you can click the blue "Run Snippet" to see it working)

```js
// no-conflict safe, shorthand document ready
jQuery(function($) {
  // Move this inside document ready (otherwise, jQuery is not available and throws an error)
  var $htmlelement = jQuery('<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">CALENDAR</span></span>');

  SetUPUI();
  $("#dddata").change(function() {
    SetUPUI();
  });


  function SetUPUI() {
    if ($('#dddata').val() == "Date") {
      $('#datetimepicker1').append($htmlelement);
      // bind datepicker to the element
      $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        format: "mm/dd/yyyy"
      });
    } else {
      // remove the proper element
      $('#datetimepicker1 span.input-group-addon').remove();
      // call destroy (remove does not work)
      $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker('remove');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-2'>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-lg-1">
        <select id="dddata">
  <option value="Text">Text</option>
  <option value="Date">Date</option>
</select>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have checked your code. in your case calendar is showing when running it....that is not right.

Comment: i want to show datepicker when date is selected from dropdown not always

Comment: why your code showing calendar when running the jsfiddle.

Comment: Because you're using a different datepicker, which uses `remove` instead of `destroy`.  Change it to `remove` in your fiddle, and I will update the answer as well.

Comment: Updated the snippet above.  Please review / test.